# Как показывать только те папки к которым есть доступ

Tags: python, minio, s3

Есть policy который даёт права на папку **Бухгалтерия** и всё что в нём.

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "s3:GetBucketLocation"
            ],
            "Resource": [
                "arn:aws:s3:::test"
            ]
        },
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "s3:ListBucket"
            ],
            "Resource": [
                "arn:aws:s3:::test"
            ],
            "Condition": {
                "StringLike": {
                    "s3:prefix": [
                        "Бухгалтерия/*"
                    ]
                }
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

Через админку minio всё смотрится канонично. Я вижу только эту папку и всё его содержимое.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Теперь в python я хочу посмотреть список доступных мне папок в корне бакета, но оно выдаёт ошибку Access Denied. Логично, т.к. я не передал `prefix=Бухгалтерия`.

```
await self.session.list_objects(bucket_name=bucket_name, recursive=False)
```

Как сделать чтобы без префикса я могу посмотреть те папки которые мне доступны?